# how to display the right movie informations in an overlay?

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm looking for solutions to display the right movie information in my overlay.
I have a "popup window" that appears when i click on a movie and it is supposed to display movie's informations in it but when I click on a movie, no matter which one it is, it only displays the last movie informations, what Should I do to fix it ?

```
const movieIntegration =() => {
    allMovies.map(movie=> {
        movieGallery.innerHTML += `<div class="imgContainer">
                                        <img src="${movie.img}" alt="${movie.name}">
                                                <div class="titleContainer">
                                                    <div class="movieTitle"> ${movie.name} </div>
                                                    <div class="seemore"> See more </div>
                                                </div>
                                    </div>`

        const seemore = document.querySelectorAll(".seemore")
        seemore.forEach(elm => {
            elm.addEventListener("click",() => {
                pageContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="popupContainer">
                                                <div class="popup">

                                                    ${movie.name}

                                                    <div id="likeButton">
                                                        <img src="img/like.png">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div id="editButton">
                                                        <img src="img/edit.png">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <a href="submit.html">
                                                        <div id="addingButton">
                                                            <img src="img/add.png">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>`
                console.log(true)
            }, true)
        })
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are getting all the `.seemore` element for each movie and you are editing the content of ALL elements for each movie, so the last movie will overwrite the content for all the previous.

A solution could be something like this:

```
const movieIntegration = () => {
  allMovies.map((movie) => {
    movieGallery.innerHTML += `<div class="imgContainer">
                                <img src="${movie.img}" alt="${movie.name}">
                                <div class="titleContainer">
                                  <div class="movieTitle"> ${movie.name} </div>
                                  <div class="seemore"> See more </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>`
  })
  const seemore = document.querySelectorAll('.seemore')
  seemore.forEach((elm, i) => {
    elm.addEventListener(
      'click',
      () => {
        pageContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="popupContainer">
                                      <div class="popup">
                                        ${allMovies[i].name}
                                        <div id="likeButton">
                                          <img src="img/like.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="editButton">
                                          <img src="img/edit.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="submit.html">
                                          <div id="addingButton">
                                            <img src="img/add.png">
                                          </div>
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>`
      },
      true
    )
  })
}
```

In this way you are mapping the `.seemore` elements AFTER you finish the map of `allMovies` and, for each `.seemore` element you get the associated movie and write his name inside.

Comment: I see but I'm not sure to understand what the "i" refers to and what it is for? could you explain it to me please ?

Comment: The `forEach` method applied take a callback function with two (really more, but in our case we need only these) parameters. The first one is the element and the second one is the current index. So for example with something like `['a', 'b', 'c'].map((e, i) => console.log(e, i)` you could see `a 0` then `b 1` then `c 2`.

Comment: ok I think I got it, one more question: you dont need to increment 'i' in the callback, it does it by itself ?

Comment: Yes, the `map` function takes care of that. You can always read the MDN docs in order to get more informations, here the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map